# Bootstrap table arrangement

Tags: html, html-table

What is the term of this table arrangement?

[image]

and I want to make a like that using bootstrap, but I fail so many times. 
(also I already google it)
that is why I am here to look someone know how to do it.

Comment: There is no name for any specific arrangement of table. It is just a table with some specific cell arrangement - that's all.

Comment: ohhh. Okay, is there anyway to done it with twitter bootstrap sir?

Comment: Bootstrap has got nothing to do with the table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/1647/)**

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Heading</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Heading</th>
        <th colspan="4">Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>SHeading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>3546 </td>
        <td>89789</td>
        <td>3546</td>
        <td>789789</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>3546 </td>
        <td>89789</td>
        <td>3546</td>
        <td>789789</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>3546 </td>
        <td>89789</td>
        <td>3546</td>
        <td>789789</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>3546 </td>
        <td>89789</td>
        <td>3546</td>
        <td>789789</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
        <td>56456757</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are specifically referring to the use of `colspan` to cover multiple columns with one cell and `rowspan` to cover multiple rows with one cell

```
<table>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">FOO</td><td colspan="4">EXAMPLE</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1. Something here</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2. Something here</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3. Something here</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4. Something here</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for quick answer sir, its very helpful :)
but I prefer Etash's answer because its more understandable for me and for others with example. cheers sir (Y)